# Testing angular controllers that have many dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a controller.

```
someModule.controller('MyController', function($rootScope, $scope, dep1, dep2) {
  ...
  $scope.aMethod = function() {
    ...
  }
  function bMethod() {
    ...
  }
  ...
}]);
```

And I define my test this way:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
console.log($controller);
    MyController = $controller('MyController', {
$rootScope : $rootScope,
$scope: scope
    });
 console.log('Some debug message');
  console.log(MyController);
  }));
```

And I get this output:

```
LOG: function (expression, locals, later, ident) { ... }
LOG: 'Some debug message'
LOG: {}
```

Even if I put in `dep1` and `dep2` I get the same results. So `scope` and `rootScope` have to be present otherwise I get an error when it runs.

I am not certain why this isn't working, as the last output is empty, so there are no functions in the controller, which is wrong.

I want to test `bMethod` as a minimum, but it appears to not be creating my controller correctly.

Comment: "I have to have the two I added, which is why they are there" ... Sorry, I'm not sure that I'm understanding the problem.  Can you state it more clearly?

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia - I added more detail.  Basically in beforeEach the MyController object has no properties or functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bMethod` it's not attached to `scope` and neither to `this`variable, therefore it's not available in the tests. There are two ways to add the method in the test:

```
$scope.bMethod = bMethod; //Attached to scope
this.bMethod = bMethod; //Attached to controller
```

In your describe block, you prints `MyController`. This it's a instance of controller. If you want get the a method provided in the example, prints `scope` and you'll see the a method.

check this codepen --> http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/WwXGxV

Answer (score 1):

There are no properties on controller instance, because they weren't defined.

It is `scope` object that has got `aMethod` property, not `MyController`:

```
expect(scope.aMethod).toBe(jasmine.any(Function));
```